# Properly Setup UIScrollView Will Not Scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIViewController which contains a UIScrollView as a subview.  This vc scrolls great when used in a UIPageViewController but the vc will not scroll when push by a nav controller.  Here are the subview sizes:

```
      Window Size {375, 667}
        Main View {{0, 64}, {375, 554}}
      Scroll View {{0, 0}, {375, 554}}
   Content Offset {0, 0}
     Content Size {375, 1160}
     Content View {{0, 0}, {375, 1160}}
```

I must be doing something wrong, but cannot see it.

Comment: Try `scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES`?  And you'd better paste more code

Comment: Added as you suggested, still no scroll.  FYI, the vc is being managed in storyboard.  What sort of code do I need to add??

Comment: Have verified that the swipe gesture make it to - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}
But goes not further.

Comment: OK, here's the push code;- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HomeViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    
    viewController.giftData = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [viewController setDelegate:self];
 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}

Comment: @JamesBonner add code editing your question, it is much more easy to read and understand